# Having to create a seperate div for each article i'm pulling from my API

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the middle of creating a website for a college project, right now I have my news API set up and can successfully pull and post data from it using JavaScript.

The way I have it set up I'm having to create a seperate div each time I want to post into one of my article fields with new data. This gets quite messy as I fundamentally want to have many articles filled up with this data and I don't want to have to keep creating separate DIV's.

Is there a way to only have one article-image div and then procedurally create new ones and fill them with API data based on the array number?

```js
var url =
  "HIDDEN_API_KEY";



var req = new Request(url);
fetch(req)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);

    document.getElementById("stadium_name").innerHTML = (res.articles[1].title);
    document.getElementById("stadium_description").innerHTML = (res.articles[1].content);
    
    var articleimg1 = document.getElementById('article-image1'); 
    articleimg1.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = (res.articles[1].urlToImage);

    document.getElementById("stadium_name2").innerHTML = (res.articles[2].title);
    document.getElementById("stadium_description2").innerHTML = (res.articles[2].content);

    var articleimg2 = document.getElementById('article-image2'); 
    articleimg2.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = (res.articles[2].urlToImage);

    document.getElementById("stadium_name3").innerHTML = (res.articles[3].title);
    document.getElementById("stadium_description3").innerHTML = (res.articles[3].content);

    var articleimg3 = document.getElementById('article-image3'); 
    articleimg3.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = (res.articles[3].urlToImage);

    document.getElementById("stadium_name4").innerHTML = (res.articles[4].title);
    document.getElementById("stadium_description4").innerHTML = (res.articles[4].content);

    var articleimg4 = document.getElementById('article-image4'); 
    articleimg4.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src = (res.articles[4].urlToImage);

    

  });
```

```html
   <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card mt-4 stadiumCard">
                    <h3 id="stadium_name"></h3>
                    <div id="article-image1"></div>
                    <p id="stadium_description">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
                        ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
                        type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card mt-4 stadiumCard">
                    <h3 id="stadium_name2"></h3>
                    <div id="article-image2"></div>
                    <p id="stadium_description2">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
                        ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
                        type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card mt-4 stadiumCard">
                    <h3 id="stadium_name3"></h3>
                    <div id="article-image3"></div>
                    <p id="stadium_description3">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
                        ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
                        type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card mt-4 stadiumCard">
                    <h3 id="stadium_name4"></h3>
                    <div id="article-image4"></div>
                    <p id="stadium_description4">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
                        ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
                        type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

                    </p>
                </div>
```

Comment: What stops you from creating these divs/articles dynamically?

Comment: You already have `document.createElement` and `element.appendChild` in your code. You can use those to dynamically create the top-level divs. All you need is a loop to iterate through your `res.articles` list

Comment: It looks like you're creating the markup before you pull your article data? If so, how do you keep that in sync? As in, what if you want to display 6 articles? I would start with an empty element and inject the full article markup after you've obtained your data.

Comment: I'm quite confident I can create the div's with document.createElement, but i'm not sure how the loop would work, any pointers :)?

Comment: I might do something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL2qsum0/1/). Loop the response array and create markup for each article as need and inject it into an existing element.

Answer (score 0):

You can create "Article" class that will handle creation of new HTML article element with nested childrens (title, img, description) and populate it's content. When you receive response from API you can loop through it and append newly created articles to HTML container. After populating this container with articles you can render all the articles at once to your client.

```js
class Article {
  constructor(ArticleData) {
    this.article = document.createElement('article');
    this.title = document.createElement('h3');
    this.img = document.createElement('img');
    this.description = document.createElement('p');
    this.populateContainer();
    this.populateContent(ArticleData);
  }
  populateContainer() {
    this.article.appendChild(this.title);
    this.article.appendChild(this.img);
    this.article.appendChild(this.description);
  }
  populateContent(ArticleData) {
    this.title.innerText = ArticleData.title;
    this.img.src = ArticleData.img;
    this.description.innerText = ArticleData.description;
  }
  getNode() {
    return this.article;
  }
}

fetch('APIendpoint')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(articles => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    fakeResponse.forEach(article => wrapper.appendChild(new Article(article).getNode()));
    document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
  })
```